# Generate Getter and Setter as generated by eclipse IDE programatically using java code

Tags: java, eclipse, getter-setter

I have a source code which will generate the getter and setter method name for my attributes. My source code is simple and it goes like this

```
String getterName= "get"+caps(attr); // caps() method makes the first character of attr to caps.
```

This code fails in certain scenarios,

for example : for attribute `cApl`

the code generated by me is `getCApl()` but the Eclipse IDE will generate it as `getcApl()`.

I am trying to perfect this code and was wondering if there is any utility/java source code which could do this just as `eclipse IDE` ? What is the logic that the IDE has adopted to do this.

Can someone put light on this?

Comment: "What is the logic that the IDE has adopted to do this" you know the source code for eclipse is publicly available, right?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Is it ? can you share the getter generation part.

Comment: It looks like `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation.GetterSetterUtil` constructs the name

Comment: If you are using eclipse and the getters and setters are strict (no shenanigans) then you could consider using lombok, which is a nice way to automate getters and setters *whithout placing them in the actual source code*. https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter I suggest you take a look, and decide, whether this is an option or not.

Comment: See source code at https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation/core%20extension/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/GetterSetterUtil.java